# How do I perform a multi-colum match in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Given two tables `T1` and `T2` with overlapping column definitions (`B` and `C`), how can I select rows in `T1` where `B` and `C` cannot be found in `T2` (in the same row?
[image: T1 without T2]
Here is the setup:

```
create table T1('A' TEXT, 'B' TEXT, 'C' TEXT);
insert into T1 values
  ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
  ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
  ('a3', 'b3', 'c3');
create table T2('B' TEXT, 'C' TEXT, 'D' TEXT);
insert into T2 values
  ('b1', 'c1', 'd1'),
  ('b2', 'c2', 'd2'),
  ('b4', 'c4', 'd4');
```

With the following query, I can select the right rows. However this is limited to columns `B` and `C` so `A` is missing:

```
select B, C from T1
intersect
select * from (select B, C from T1
               except
               select B, C from T2);
-- this yields:
-- b3|c3
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
select * from T1
intersect
select * from (select B, C from T1
               except
               select B, C from T2);
-- this yields:
-- Error: SELECTs to the left and right of INTERSECT do not have the same number of result columns
```

(Note the `*` in the first `select` statement.) I can't seem to grasp the concept of selecting rows with a subquery and returning full rows.

**How do I have to change the query so that the result is `a3|b3|c3`?**

By the way, this is a real life example where I have a dump of filenames from a restoration of a file system and I want to know which files are missing from the restoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the best/most elegant solution but the following appears to work :-

```
SELECT A, X1B AS B, X1C AS C FROM
    (select X1.B AS X1B, X1.C AS X1C from T1 AS X1
       except
       select T2.B, T2.C from T2) 
JOIN T1 ON B = X1B AND C = X1C
```

or :-

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM
    (select X1.B AS X1B, X1.C AS X1C from T1 AS X1
        except
        select T2.B, T2.C from T2) 
JOIN T1 ON B = X1B AND C = X1C
```

Resulting in :-

[image]

Comment: Based on above answer I ended up with `select * from T1 except select T1.* from T1 join T2 on T1.B = T2.B and T1.C = T2.C;`. I found the renamings of the columns from your example a little bit confusing so I tried to get around that. From my perspective the revised query is easier to understand. But maybe that's my lack of experience with SQL. @MikeT Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Pascal no yours is better, it's less convoluted.